# Terraform: Create resources from a list of maps with nested lists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, subnet, terraform-variables

I need to create multiple subnets in AWS using Terraform, and wanted to make the process as easily repeatable and standardized as possible.  I would like to create a variable with a `list` of `maps` that contains the information necessary to create the subnets, like this:

```
my_subnet_map = [
  {
    name = "subnetA",
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
  },
  {
    name = "subnetB",
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  },
  {
    name = "subnetC",
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.3.0/24", "10.0.4.0/24"]
  },
  ...
]
```

I envisioned being able to do something like this:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
   count = ???
   vpc_id = var.vpc_id
   availability_zone = XXX

   cidr_block = var.my_subnet_map[SOME KIND OF LOOKUP]

}
```

I know how to use `count` or `for_each` to loop over values, but in this case the values have a varying number of `cidr_blocks`.  So, the `count` doesn't correspond to the number of entries in the `list`.  It corresponds to the TOTAL number of `cidr_block` values across all members of the `list`.

How would I accomplish something like this?  It almost seems like some sort of nested `count` to me, but I'm not familiar enough with Terraform to know how to model it.  Thoughts?

Comment: The goal is to have a `aws_subnet` resource per `cidr_block`? What do you intend to use `name` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data structure you've shown here is a sequence of *objects*, and might have the following type if declared as an input variable:

```
list(object({
  name        = string
  cidr_blocks = set(string)
}))
```

The name "my_subnet_map" is therefore a little confusing, because there aren't any maps here. I mention this only because to make this work you will need to project this list of objects into a map of objects, since that's what `for_each` requires, and so having these names straight will make things less confusing as we start deriving other collections from this initial one.

It also seems like this is a list of "subnet groups" -- a concept you've invented yourself, which I've now named -- where each object represents a set of subnets. So for clarity, let's name it `subnet_groups`, and I'll also add a few type explicit conversions just to make it clearer what types we're going for here:

```
locals {
  subnet_groups = tolist([
    {
      name = "subnetA",
      cidr_blocks = toset(["10.0.0.0/24"])
    },
    {
      name = "subnetB",
      cidr_blocks = toset(["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"])
    },
    {
      name = "subnetC",
      cidr_blocks = toset(["10.0.3.0/24", "10.0.4.0/24"])
    },
    ...
  ])
}
```

To get this into the shape that `aws_subnet` needs it'll be necessary to flatten this to be a collection with one element per actual subnet, *not* per subnet group. Here's one way to do that:

```
locals {
  subnets = toset(flatten([
    for group in local.subnet_groups : [
      for cidr_block in group.cidr_blocks : {
        group_name = group.name
        cidr_block = cidr_block
      }
    ]
  ]))
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each = tomap({
    for subnet in local.subnets :
    "${subnet.group_name}:${subnet.cidr_block}" => subnet
  })

  vpc_id     = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block = each.value.cidr_block
}
```

The expression assigned to `subnets` is intended to construct a flat set of objects shaped like this:

```
toset([
  {
    group_name = "subnetA"
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
  },
  {
    group_name = "subnetB"
    cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  },
  {
    group_name = "subnetB"
    cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
  },
  {
    group_name = "subnetC"
    cidr_block = "10.0.3.0/24"
  },
  {
    group_name = "subnetC"
    cidr_block = "10.0.4.0/24"
  },
])
```

`for_each` in a `resource` block requires a map with a unique key to track each instance by though, so in the actual `for_each` expression I projected this once more into a map with some keys containing both the group name and the CIDR block to make sure they are all unique. With the set of subnet groups we started with, that would declare the following resource instances:

- `aws_subnet.private["subnetA:10.0.0.0/24"]`
- `aws_subnet.private["subnetB:10.0.1.0/24"]`
- `aws_subnet.private["subnetB:10.0.2.0/24"]`
- `aws_subnet.private["subnetC:10.0.3.0/24"]`
- `aws_subnet.private["subnetC:10.0.4.0/24"]`

---

References:

- [The `flatten` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten)
- [`for_each` for resources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each)
- [`for` expressions for deriving collections from other collections](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for)
- [Terraform's types](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#types)

Comment: Thank you!  This is very informative!  I was not familiar with the flatten method.  I think that was the piece I was really missing.